# Errno::EACCES solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've been hounded by the above error whenever my rails project has to alter the filesystem. Be it carrierwave image uploads or creating a folder via

```
Dir.mkdir
```

Lately I'm getting this error because the gem I'm using wants to create a directory at `/home/git/repositories` and it can't because it hits this permission error.

I know this is a stupid idea, but in desperation I've set `/home` recursively to `7777` and, against all sense and reason, I'm still getting

```
Errno::EACCES at /users
Permission denied
```

I've been hounded by this error. I had the same thing with carrierwave, even when I set its directory recursively to `7777`

Same thing with paperclip too.

I fixed carrierwave by deleting the directory and letting carrierwave create the directory structure itself when it saw the directories weren't there. It was the only way I could do it, after much hair-pulling and setting **every directory** on my machine to `7777`! (did it in a VM because I know how silly that is :P)

Is this something to do with the application server? What user is running the application server? I thunk that may be the key because it fixed the error when the application server created the directories, rather than myself doing it manually. But I just run the server normally, under my own account... the same account that creates the directories and sets the permissions... What am I doing wrong to continually hit this error?

Can I run something along the lines of `sudo rails s`?

Also I can't let the system create the directories because then I get a 'directory not found error'. I know I'm on the right lines because upon using mkdir manually to create `/home/git/repositories` I started getting `Permission denied` errors instead.

Answer (score 0):

You probably don't want the stickbit/setuser/setgroup bits. Maybe you want 0664 instead, which grants read/write to the owning user/group, and read to other users.

If it's trying to write in `/users` then the problem is probably that `/users` doesn't exist and your root `/` only permits root to create directories. You should probably verify which paths it's trying to write to; just slinging permissive modes around is a) probably not going to solve the problem, b) leaves you open to security issues, and c) is a really bad habit to get in to.

Running your rails app as root will work, but is a truly awful idea. Don't do it.